# Angular reactive form + material input don't show red border on first focus when input is not valide

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material, angular-reactive-forms

I have an Angular Reactive Form with child component inputs with custom validator.

I got a strange behavior:

When I select an input the first time then I put value that invalidates the field, I don't get red borders but I see that the form control in not valid. the borders changes color only when I unfocus the field.
Then when I go back on it and update values I get "live" UI validations of the inputed text every caracter change.

```
export class FormFieldErrorExample {
  email = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.email]);

  getErrorMessage() {
    if (this.email.hasError('required')) {
      return 'You must enter a value';
    }

    return this.email.hasError('email') ? 'Not a valid email' : '';
  }
}
```

**Html**

```
<div class="example-container">
  <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter your email</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="pat@example.com" [formControl]="email" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="email.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

An example in the [official angular material site](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages) at the email

What I need is to change input validation style starting from first focus.

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution , When I build the form dynamically , I have added the property `markAllAsTouched()` to the formGroup .

Now when I put a wrong value for the first time I get directly the input with red borders without the need to unfocus it to see wether my text is valid or not.

I don't know if it's the best solution. I'm interested still in other vision